# Using PDFBox, how to set an appearance stream on annotation?

Tags: java, image, annotations, pdfbox

I am trying to highlight some text and convert it to image.
I tried some stuff but the annotation did not came out on the image.
Looking for help found this issue
http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2162
which said that I must set appearance-stream to the annotation, something that acrobat reader do it automatically, but when converting to image it is needed. I could not figure out how to set the appearance-stream to the annotation.
looked for some examples on annotations and appearance-stream
(which I could not find an example that do both.. :-(  )

This is what I have so far:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("sometest.pdf");
List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage page = pages.get(0);
List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
PDAnnotationTextMarkup annotation = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);

final PDRectangle boundingBox = new PDRectangle();
//here I set the boundingbox coordinates
annotation.setRectangle(boundingBox);

final float[] quads = this.getQuads(boundingBox);
annotation.setQuadPoints(quads);
annotation.setContents("bla bla");
annotation.setConstantOpacity((float) 0.9);
PDGamma c = new PDGamma();
//Here I set the RGB
annotation.setColour(c);
annotation.setPrinted(true);
//create the Form for the appearance stream
PDResources holderFormResources = new PDResources();
PDStream holderFormStream = new PDStream(document);
PDXObjectForm holderForm = new PDXObjectForm(holderFormStream);
holderForm.setResources(holderFormResources);
holderForm.setBBox(boundingBox);
holderForm.setFormType(1);
// trying to set the appreanceStream for the annotation
PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(holderForm.getCOSStream());
holderForm.getCOSStream().createFilteredStream();
appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);

annotation.setAppearance(appearance);

annotations.add(annotation);
//convert to image
BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR, 600);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("test.jpg"));
document.save("test.pdf");
document.close();
```

The "test.pdf" come out with the annotation, but the image not.

What am I missing?

Comment: If the PDF displays fine with Adobe Reader but the rendered image doesn't look OK, then you should open an issue in JIRA and attach that PDF. There is at one bug involving rendering of annotations that was solved (PDFBOX-2283) for the unreleased 2.0 version but not for the 1.8 version (see patch in PDFBOX-2001).

Comment: Your code creates an *empty* appearance stream which PDFBox renders faithfully into the JPEG. You see something in the PDF viewer because the PDF viewer, sensing the empty appearance, creates an appearance of its choice.

Comment: OK, so how can create an appearance-stream with content that will be rendered into the JPEG?

Comment: Sadly, now that it is clarified what you meant, it is a known bug, also in PDF.js, see PDFBOX-2019.

Comment: I am having similar issue, @chico , Did you find the solution for this ? If yes, It would be very helpful.

Comment: Since 2.0.16 the appearance stream of many annotation types can be created with annotation.constructAppearances().