# Workaround for known Bug in PDFBox

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

first of all: My goal is to just load a PDF, highlight words from that PDF (Page) and show that Page / PDF to the user as Image.

Till now i parse the PDF with a custom Text-Stripper to get all word-positions with their coordinates ( needed to generate a rectangle for highlighting later)

After that i started to generate PDAnnotationTextMarkup's so. Now i'm at this point where i can see my annotations well if i save the pdf to a file and view it with a PDFReader by choice. But if i use the convertToImage Method given by PDFBox, i only get a normal page rendered without annotations.

After a little time on google i found: [PDFBOX-2019](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2019) which was mentioned in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994748/using-pdfbox-how-to-set-an-appearance-stream-on-annotation)

Now im looking for a workaround because i think the ticket history is showing that no one will fix that issue in about a year.

Anybody a good idea to fix that and achieve my goal?

thanks in advance
ben

Comment: The easiest solution would be that you generate the appearance youself (the AP entry, see the comment of Maruan in the issue). To see how an appearance looks like, take a different PDF (with annotation like yours and that renders in PDFBox, i.e. where the appearance is set within the PDF) and open it with PDFBox PDFDebugger.

Comment: Hey Tilman, i think i found a pdf file via google that works with a pdfviewer (evince) and works so that pdfbox export a valid image showing the annotations. ( http://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_commenting_new.pdf ) - im a little new to pdfbox so , do you may have a link for me to see the pdfdebugger class working? where do i get the appearence from?  and how do i rebuild this appearance in my generated PDF ? Thanks in advance :-/

Comment: Okay, the debugger is self-explaining --- how to get the appereance out of that and how to rebuild unfurtionally not :(

Comment: Yes, it's not easy. The 20th annotation contains an AP entry. This is an XForm, although the API doesn't treat it like that. And you'd need to have an understanding of PDF operators, so that you understand what your sample does.

Comment: Thanks a lot. if I'm honest to myself, i think I'M not the right man to achieve this :D - I'm not that deep into the PDF format as i have to , to solve this. i think i have to wait for 2.0 / 2.1 [2.0 doesn't do what i want also ;-) - but that's what was written on jira at all]. or i have to choose a different lib.... mhhh . thanks anyhow :)